# Can I use the Gmail API to get the MD5 hash value for an attachment?

Tags: javascript, gmail, email-attachments

I work in an email security software company and we are currently faced with the question of being able to identify attachments in emails. Since we are cloud hosted, we need to be able to do this with Gmail and Outlook. It looks like the Outlook API will give you an atttachment hash under ContentBytes, but Gmail looks very limited in the attachment data it gives back to you.

Is there something I'm missing here?

Comment: 2 things: i thought gmail uses TLS, so you shouldn't need a hash to validate. Also if the MD5 is coming from the same server, it's useless as a hacker can alter it and the attachment at the same time.

Comment: My intent with this may not be entirely clear, I would like to be able to compare a MD5 hash of a known "good" (authentic) attachment with a hash of a received email to expedite attachment analysis

Comment: fair enough, that's fine as long is it's not from "the same server"...

Answer (score 0):

Attachments in emails are classified as content types in email.

Which you want to do is pull the content types off the emails

Emails with attachments usually have more than 1 content type associated to it.

Take a look at this RFC: https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2045.txt

In an email I had, I looked at the RAW Text of one that had a PDF attachment and seen this content type.

```
Content-Type: application/pdf;
```

Then one that had an image attached to it.

```
Content-Type: image/jpeg;
```

You wouldn't need a special API to read this, just get the raw text of the message and parse it out.

Comment: I'm trying to get the MD5 hashes that identify the content of the attachments, not the types of files that they are.